# How to handle Non English Characters in web.config?

Tags: web-config

I have some non English characters being stored in my web.config file. I am able to save, close and reopen the file in notepad and everything looks good.

When I try run the app, I get this error: Configuration file is not well-formed XML.

How can I store non English characters in web.config?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you add the normal XML encoding header?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
```

Also, you will need to save your file in the appropriate format.