# How to allow unicode characters in web.config for my MVC application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, unicode, web-config

I wanted to add some cool characters to the names and added in my *web.config* a picture of a cow, like this.

```
<add key="SenderName" value="&#x1f3eb; Mr Mooo"/>
```

However, when I start the application, I get an exception on this line in my *_Layout.cshtml* nagging about localization and such.

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
```

I'm not sure how to handle this. Apparently, the MVC hates cows but what can I do about it?

I've tried to follow [the suggested syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19346681/1525840) according to the [standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML#Escaping). I also added [UTF-16 at the top](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3308263/1525840) of the config file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing at all to do with Unicode characters and everything to do with XML escaping.

As stated in the [XML Standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML#Escaping) you linked to, XML only defines 5 standard entities:

- `&lt;` represents `<`
- `&gt;` represents `>`
- `&amp;` represents `&`
- `&apos;` represents `'`
- `&quot;` represents `"`

All other entities (such as `&#x1f3eb;`) are not valid in XML unless you explicitly define them.

There is an easy way out of this situation, though. The problem with this entity is that it contains an ampersand that is NOT escaped, which makes it incompatible with XML. You just need to escape it and all is right with the world.

```
<add key="SenderName" value="&amp;#x1f3eb; Mr Mooo"/>
```

Now your *application* will receive the unescaped string you want: `&#x1f3eb; Mr Mooo` when you retrieve it from the config file, and you can then pass it on to the view.

Answer (score 2):

Try to set encoding both in header and in configuration node for system.web- set globalization node "fileEncoding" attribute to utf-16.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <globalization fileEncoding="utf-16" requestEncoding="utf-16" responseEncoding="utf-16"/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

P.S. Sorry - last time I was typing from my tablet so it was hard to wrote an example.

Comment: Not sure if I understand correctly. By header, you mean the topmost line in *web.config*, right? But the other one? I'd love to see a tiny sample in the answer.

Comment: For the record - I haven't downvoted this. And I'll be happy to grant you +1 if you suggest a sample.